# Want to add href link for each checkbox in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, croogo

```
 echo $this->Form->input('name_group', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $val,'label' => false,'class' => 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 custom_no_padding custom_checkbox','selected' => $selected));
```

And Want to output like as below:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 custom_no_padding custom_checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<label><a href="test1">Value1</label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 custom_no_padding custom_checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"><label><a href="test2">Value2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Interactive elements ```<a></a>``` inside interactive elements ```<label></label>``` cause functional problems.

Comment: @Salines so isn't there any way for me to achieve it??

Comment: Use just links whitout labels.

Comment: @Salines can you please share demo code so that i can understand it properly!!!thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place? Sounds like a rather bad UI design choice, predestinated to trip users. Anyways, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks!